# Could not execute menu item (internal error) ... cannot find file when attempting to access httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf

Tags: php, mysql, apache, amazon-ec2, wampserver

I set up an AWS EC2 (Windows Server 2012 R2 Base), allowing inbound RDP, HTTP, and HTTPS and installed Wampserver and the VS update for both 64 and 32 bit from Microsoft.  When trying to access the site from a different computer, I get a 403 forbidden error.  Most posts on the forum state that to fix this error I need to make changes to httpd.conf and/or httpd-vhosts.conf.

When I try to select either of those from the Wampserver icon to make those changes, however, I get the following error message:

Could not execute menu item (internal error) [Exception] Could not execute run action: The system cannot find the file specified.

I also get this error when trying to access the Apache error log and access log, so I cannot provide any information from those files.  I also get this error when trying to access PHP and MySQL logs.  Apache is version 2.4.23 and PHP is version 5.6.25.

There are several posts regarding this error, but none that I could find that address this problem.  All of the ones I found for other situations where this error occurs recommend accessing the files that I cannot access in order to fix the problem.

The error seems to imply that I'm missing certain files, but I didn't make any changes when installing, haven't loaded any previous configuration, and, as I said, the icon is green.  I've tried restarting all services as well as stopping/starting all services.  I've verified that Apache is using port 80, but that's as far as I can get.

I'm completely new to all of this, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the port, and testing the used port